# Advantages/Disadvantages of server-less Subversion for solo developer

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN is good for this?

What about best practices to work fine?

Any special care about tricky issues using that way?

Comment: SVN server that is simple to set up: http://www.visualsvn.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a single developer it is ok.
But I strictly discourage from using it with more than one developer.

The SVN book says:

> Do not be seduced by the simple idea
>   of having all of your users access a
>   repository directly via file:// URLs.
>   Even if the repository is readily
>   available to everyone via network
>   share, this is a bad idea. It removes
>   any layers of protection between the
>   users and the repository: users can
>   accidentally (or intentionally)
>   corrupt the repository database, it
>   becomes hard to take the repository
>   offline for inspection or upgrade, and
>   it can lead to a mess of
>   file-permissions problems (see the
>   section called “Supporting Multiple
>   Repository Access Methods”.) Note that
>   this is also one of the reasons we
>   warn against accessing repositories
>   via svn+ssh://  URLs—from a security
>   standpoint, it's effectively the same
>   as local users accessing via file://,
>   and can entail all the same problems
>   if the administrator isn't careful.

(From: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html)

Installing svnserve isn't that complicated and it's really worth putting an hour or two in configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Obvious downside: even if you're using RAID so you've got redundancy on the disks, if your computer is lost or stolen, you're hosed. If you've got the source hosted on a server somewhere, then if *either* the server *or* your client machine gets stolen, you'll have another copy. (Admittedly if the server is stolen you'll lose history and branches, but it's better than nothing.)

Answer (score 0):

I do this. I use a shared folder called SVN. Inside this folder is each of my subversion repositories for various projects.

Have not had any issues. I now host this on a RAID 5 array for redundancy.

I should point out that have been doing this for over 3 years.

I also set this up in a corporate environment for the last 2 years where the repository has had over 200 checkins and the size is over 200Mb.

Comment: corporate environment without svnserve or svn webDAV server? That's a bad idea, i would not recommend.

Comment: If you are 2-3 people in an organisation of thousands, and the drive share is controlled via active directory, and it costs thousands to host a simple VM just for web based access, I would go the simple method. Also the drive share is backed up and rotated regulary.

Comment: Your data, not mine. But I won't recommend it to someone else as easy as you did. Accessing simultaneously the same files over SMB isn't what I call a safe method. If you are only 2 or 3 people, you could manage that by shouting your locks to the others, true. I have seen similar approaches for a complete working copy. *Runs away, crying in horror and pulling his hair out*

Comment: Master repository over SMB. Local repository on local machine. This is for SQL data files, documentation. I was the main committer. Granted not for a proper enterprise where many developers are needed, but using SVNServe was not a viable option in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I used to run a Linux box just to host a SVN server (I do almost all my development on Windows) but I got fed up with it howling away under my desk and switched to single-user SVN hosted on Windows. I've had no problems (touch wood) but I do take care to back up all my SVN repositories frequently, so that at most I could lose a days worth of work. No need for complex backup procedures, just buy yourself a few USB flash memory thingies and simply copy the SVN archive directories to them.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is that you must be very careful with permissions. I found some occasional troubles in a solo-developer configuration, so if something acts weird check permissions and lock status of the repository first. If you have like me multiple unrelated projects, what I do is to create a dir for each project, and into this dir I put two subdirs: SVN which contains the repo for the project, and "checkout" which contains the actual checkout. I use this approach because I have automatic backup of my home directory, hence I get to backup both the project and its repository. Alternatively, you can put the repo somewhere else (which must be kept backed-up).